The first column of my table seems to be pushing the other 2 columns to the right and i cant change it
I want all the columns to be together towards the left side of the table, but nothing i do is able to change the gap between the first column and the second(and third) columns. How do i fix this?
<body>
        <h1>Calculator</h1>
        <table class="my-table">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" value="1"></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="2"></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" value="4"></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="5"></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="6"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" value="7"></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="8"></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="9"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </body>
</html>

how it looks on the browser
I've tried changing the width of tr and nothing changes.
I've tried changing the "tr td:first-child" width and nothing changes.
I'm able to create a border and add background color but for some reason i can't change the size of the content box (of each first row for the first column)
i figured out that the input on top is what's affecting my table. I'm still not able to do what i want to do while keeping the input there though.

Don't use a table here. Use CSS-Grid.

Text inputs have a default size, you have to change that or see above.

Are you looking for colspan="3"?

As @Paulie_D has suggested, using CSS-grids is a more wise and better choice to achieve things like a calculator layout.
Look at this example:


body {
  width: 50%;
}

.my-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.my-grid input[type="text"] {
  grid-column: span 3;
}
<body>
  <h1>Calculator</h1>

  <div class="my-grid">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="button" value="1">
    <input type="button" value="2">
    <input type="button" value="3">
    <input type="button" value="4">
    <input type="button" value="5">
    <input type="button" value="6">
    <input type="button" value="7">
    <input type="button" value="8">
    <input type="button" value="9">
  </div>
</body>






<h1>Calculator</h1>

<table class="my-table">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><input type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="2"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="4"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="5"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="6"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="7"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="8"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="9"></td>
  </tr>
</table>



the <td> containing the <input type="text"> element uses colspan="3", which makes it span three columns. This allows the input field to be wider and occupy the entire row width, aligning it better with the buttons. This can make the calculator display look more organized and visually appealing.

Flexbox is pretty cool too.


body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 50%;
}

.calculator {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 5px;
}

.calculator input[type="text"] {
    flex-basis: calc(100% - 10px);
}

.calculator input[type="button"] {
    flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 5px);
}
<h1>Calculator</h1>

<div class="calculator">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="button" value="1" />
    <input type="button" value="2" />
    <input type="button" value="3" />
    <input type="button" value="4" />
    <input type="button" value="5" />
    <input type="button" value="6" />
    <input type="button" value="7" />
    <input type="button" value="8" />
    <input type="button" value="9" />
</div>




I see. I currently don't know how to use flexbox but this solution looks much better. Thank you.

@Charles Flexbox is pretty easy, you can learn it anytime, and you're welcome.
